# D3D11のデバッグレイヤーで出る警告が取れない

Tags: c++, directx

以下の警告文が出力ウィンドウに表示されます。

> D3D11 WARNING: ID3D11DeviceContext::OMSetRenderTargets: Resource being set to OM RenderTarget slot 0 is still bound on input! [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #9: DEVICE_OMSETRENDERTARGETS_HAZARD]
>   D3D11 WARNING: ID3D11DeviceContext::OMSetRenderTargets[AndUnorderedAccessViews]: Forcing PS shader resource slot 0 to NULL. [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #7: DEVICE_PSSETSHADERRESOURCES_HAZARD]

ググった所、OMSetRenderTargets()で設定しようとしているビューのリソースが、すでにピクセルシェーダのシェーダリソースビューとして割り当てられている為のようです。
解決策として、OMSetRenderTarget()とPSSetShaderResources()にNULLを渡してステートをリセットすればいいみたいなことが書かれていました。

なので、OMSetRenderTarget()を呼び出す前に、

```
ID3D11RenderTargetView* dummyRTVs[D3D11_SIMULTANEOUS_RENDER_TARGET_COUNT] = {nullptr};
ID3D11ShaderResourceView* dummySRVs[D3D11_COMMONSHADER_INPUT_RESOURCE_SLOT_COUNT] = {nullptr};

pImmediateContext->OMSetRenderTargets( _countof(dummyRTVs), dummyRTVs, nullptr);
pImmediateContext->PSSetShaderResources( 0, _countof(dummySRVs), dummySRVs);
```

という処理を実行しているのですが、相変わらずおなじ警告文を吐いてしまいます。
何か他に原因があるのでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `OMSetRenderTarget()`を呼び出す前ではなく、毎回の描画後に後片付けをする必要があるのではないでしょうか。[こちら](http://bate.hatenadiary.jp/entry/20120630/1341065633) のような記事が見つけられました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
全ての描画後に上記の処理を追加しましたが、変わりませんでした。何かを見落としているのかもしれません。

Answer (score 3):

この警告は同じリソースを同時にread/writeするときに発生します。
例えばピクセルシェーダーで描き込もうとするレンダーターゲットをさらにテクスチャとしてピクセルシェーダーにバインドするとこのような警告が出ます。
よくある例としてはバックバッファをテクスチャとして貼ったエフェクトや深度バッファを使ったシャドウマップなどです。
リソースにNULLを設定したとしても同じタイミングで読み書きをしているパスがあると発生してしまうので丁寧にコードを調査する必要があります。
コードをパスごとにコメントアウトして原因を絞り込み、そのような使い方をしているところがないか探してみてください。